# Android ftp download doesn't downloads file properly

Tags: java, android, ftp

I'm new on android  programming. And I need to download videos, jpgs and pdfs from an ftp server to my android device.

Here is my download code in a Thread

```
      MyFTPClient ftpclient=null;
      ftpclient = new MyFTPClient();
      status = ftpclient.ftpConnect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "username", "password", 21);
      if (status == true) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Connection Success");
          FTPFile[] filelist= ftpclient.ftpPrintFilesList("/httpdocs/");
          for(int i=0;i<filelist.length;i++){
              if(filelist[i].getType()==1)
              {
                   File myFile = new File("/storage/sdcard0/App/"+filelist[i].getName());
                   if(!myFile.exists()){
                      File folder=new File("/storage/sdcard0/App/"+filelist[i].getName());
                      folder.mkdir();
                   }
               }
               else if(filelist[i].getType()==0)
               {
                    ftpclient.ftpDownload("/httpdocs/"+filelist[i].getName(), "/storage/sdcard0/App/"+filelist[i].getName());
               }
          }
          else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed");
          }
```

This is my FTP client class

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
                          String password, int port)
{
    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
        mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            return status;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host+"Cause: "+e.getCause() );
    }
    return false;
} 


public FTPFile[] ftpPrintFilesList(String dir_path)
{
    try {
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
        int length = ftpFiles.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
            boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();

            if (isFile) {
                Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
            }
        }

        return ftpFiles;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
} 

public boolean ftpDownload(String srcFilePath, String desFilePath)
{
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(desFilePath);;
        status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);
        desFileStream.flush();
        desFileStream.close();

        return status;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "download failed");
    }

    return status;
}
```

These codes dowloads files but when I want to open some pdfs or videos I get error "An error occured while opening the document"

How can I handle the dowload code works properly? What can be the reasen of the error?

P.S: The video files are 100-200 MB, pdf files are 1-5 MB

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to open the download files and maybe more details about the error (stacktrace) ?

Comment: No I'm trying to open files on device, not with code.

Comment: Why are you setting this inside your login method? mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE); Should be left as binary at the end...

Comment: @Martin you should write your comment as an answer. I would bet on it to be the solution to the problem.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks everyone. when I "mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);" put this line from ftpConnect function to ftpDownload function, the problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting this inside your login method? mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE); Should be left as binary at the end...